# Create an overview of users that can edit / view specific folders within Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

We have a share Google Drive environment where different folders are shared with several people. Per folder I can see who currently has access to the folder.

For compliance purposes I want to create an overview per folder with how has access. A little like this:

GENERAL: Josh, Henk, Andrew
GENERAL/CLASSIFIED: Josh, Henk
CLASSIFIED: Josh

Does anybody now of a way I can do this without having to go the specific folder time after time?

Answer (score 0):

You can bookmark the page you're on when you're inside the folder, clicking the bookmark will load Drive inside that folder. You could also add the folder to Starred items, and use that to find it more quickly.